# change.org javascript API - unauthorized request error

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to use javascript API from change.org to get all my signed petitions
because i want to put it on my source forge page
But i'm having unauthorized request as answer from change.org API

I already tried many things like using api_secret and secret, but it always return 'unauthorized request'

Any suggestion is very welcomed :)

I'm using the following javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>change.org test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./sha256.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./changeorgapi.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getAllPetitions() {
var client  = new ChangeOrgApiClient({
"api_key" : "omitted for security",
"secret"  : "omitted for security"
});

var user = new ChangeOrgApiUser(client);

user.setCallback(function(response) {
alert("message: " + JSON.stringify(response.getData()));
});

user.getSignedPetitions({
"user_id" : 31368676,
"fields" : "title,url,signature_count",
"page_size" : 5,
"page" : 1,
"sort" : "signatures_asc"
});
}

getAllPetitions();
</script>
</head>
<body>change.org test</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Things that come in mind: 
1) You are not sending your credentials in the request so they refuse your request.
2) You are sending invalid credentials. Look at the API documentation to know how they validate that you are a valid user https://github.com/change/api_docs/blob/master/v1/documentation/requests.md

Comment: I will double-check the documentation, i suppose it's sort of a simple thing that i missed on the way, don't know for sure

Comment: if you found a workaround post it as an answer. So users that stuck in the same step will found a solution.

Comment: Hello! I actually opened a case on change.org support
I'm waiting their answer

Answer (score 1):

After reading this [tutorial](https://www.change.org/developers/tutorials/a-basic-request) I followed this step in order to make a succefull request to the change API.

1) Register on the page.

2) Get the API key from account page.

3) Generate the request as the example shows:

Base url: https://api.change.org/v1/petitions/get_id
Url with params: https://api.change.org/v1/petitions/get_id?api_key=myapikey&petition_url=somevalidpetitionurl.

4) Check if the GET request to that url works as expected using curl

5) Replicated my request from my javascript application (actually copied the curl request from chrome browser)

So if everything works for you from 1 to 4. The API Works as expected with your credentials and the problem is the message that the javascript applications send. If fails in step 4, something is bad with the url or the credentials (Check & repeat).

Curl example:

curl 'https://api.change.org/v1/petitions/get_id?api_key=putTheApiKeyHere(NotprivateKey)&petition_url=https://www.provider.org/p123123/123123123 -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: */*'  --compressed

Answer (score 0):

`GET petitions/:petition_id/signatures` is deprecated but `GET petitions/:petition_id/signatures/recent` (last 10) still works.